# Multithreaded groovy sql update

Tags: sql, multithreading, groovy, sybase

I have code that does a select from one database and then processes to update another database. It has a bunch of fields (around a 100), and there are about 4 million rows, so the process is pretty slow, around 4 hours to do the whole thing. I am thinking on how I can improve this time, I already implemented batching, doesn't seem to get too much performance though. Now I am thinking if I should do multithreading and if there is a groovy way to do it. 
Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
Sql sql1 = Sql.newInstance(config.db.url, config.db.login, config.db.password, config.db.driver);
String queryText = "select  " + config.sql1.fields.join(",") +" from myTable"

Sql sql2 = Sql.newInstance(config.sql2.db.url, config.sql2.db.login, config.sql2.db.password, config.sql2.db.driver);
String updateSqlText = "update table2 set "+ config.sql2.fields.join("=?,") + "=?  where id=?";

sql2.cacheStatements = true

def updateCounts = sql2.withBatch(100, updateSqlText) { ps ->
    sql1.eachRow(queryText){row ->
        def resultList = []
        row.getMetaData().getColumnCount().times{
            def value = row.getAt(it)
            resultList.add(value)
        }
            resultList.add(row.SUD_ID)
            ps.addBatch(resultList)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Multi-threaded would somewhat help - you'd have to experiment to determine the ideal thread count **on the machine** it would be running on.  If the processing is minimal, and to avoid the i/o, can it be moved to a stored procedure?

Comment: Of course, depending on the database and locking strategy, it may also be slower...

Comment: Have you tried increasing the batch size?

Comment: Yes, I tried 100 and 1000, it's almost the same speed. It's page locking on that table.

Comment: Can't be done in stored procedure since it's in two different databases on different servers.

Comment: Is there a way to group by the page id a row is in with Sybase ? If so, with an extra step, you could ensure each thread has exclusive access to the target update pages and multiple threads would not contend with each other.

Comment: Don't think there is visibility into pages and I don't want to be db specific. I am rewriting perl code and Groovy looks to be about 30% slower now. Perl is single-threaded. I need to somehow increase the speed.